# Function boundary identification using libclang

Tags: python, clang, llvm, clang++, libclang

I am learning to parse C++ files using Python + libclang with the help of this very informative (but slightly outdated) tutorial by [Eli Bendersky](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/07/03/parsing-c-in-python-with-clang).

My objective is to parse C++ files and identify the function boundaries for functions present in those file. I am expecting to build a python dictionary of this form:

`{<func_name>:(<func_start_loc>, <func_end_loc>), ...}`

To this end, I am able to get the function name (using `cursor.spelling` for AST nodes that are of `CursorKind.FUNCTION_DECL` or `CursorKind.CXX_METHOD` kind) and the start location (using `cursor.location`)

My question is, how do I get the end of function location

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for the `extent` property on the `Cursor` class. For example:

```
s = '''
void f();
void g() 
{}
void f() 
{}
'''

idx = clang.cindex.Index.create()
tu = idx.parse('tmp.cpp', unsaved_files=[('tmp.cpp', s)])
for f in tu.cursor.walk_preorder():
    if f.kind == CursorKind.FUNCTION_DECL:
        print f.extent
```

Will return a Python equivalent of a source range:

```
<SourceRange start <SourceLocation file 'tmp.cpp', line 2, column 1>, end <SourceLocation file 'tmp.cpp', line 2, column 9>>
<SourceRange start <SourceLocation file 'tmp.cpp', line 3, column 1>, end <SourceLocation file 'tmp.cpp', line 4, column 3>>
<SourceRange start <SourceLocation file 'tmp.cpp', line 5, column 1>, end <SourceLocation file 'tmp.cpp', line 6, column 3>>
```

You may want to consider restricting attention to definitions using `Cursor.is_definition` if you want function bodies rather than just their declarations.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include "clang/Basic/SourceManager.h"

FunctionDecl *f;

SourceLocation ST = f->getSourceRange().getBegin();
SourceLocation ED = f->getSourceRange().getEnd();
```

https://github.com/eliben/llvm-clang-samples/blob/master/src_clang/rewritersample.cpp

https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1FunctionDecl.html
https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1SourceRange.html